# Check if a Field is a TList with Reflection

Tags: list, delphi, reflection, tlist

Using Delphi how can I check if a field of an object is a TList ?

I tryed using this

```
var
  c : TRttiContext;
  t : TRttiType;
  f : TRttiField;
begin
  c := TRttiContext.Create;
    t := c.GetType(Self.ClassType);
    for f in t.GetFields do begin
      //check if the field is TList<T>
      //check also the Generic type T 
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `IsType<T>` method if you want to check for `TList` (the one from `System.Classes`).

If you want to check if it is a `TList<T>` you have to do some string parsing of the class name. Even more so if you want to check the specific type of `T`. This is because Delphi has no special RTTI about generic types and it does not support open generic types.

You can look at the `Spring.Helpers` unit from Spring4D how this can be solved.

Some example code using this:

```
if f.FieldType.IsGenericType then
  if f.FieldType.GetGenericTypeDefinition = 'TList<>' then
    if f.FieldType.GetGenericArguments[0].Handle = TypeInfo(TMyClass) then
      Writeln('found');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check if object contains `ToArray()` method:

```
var
  method: TRttiMethod;
begin
  ...
  method := f.FieldType.GetMethod('ToArray');
  if Assigned(method) then
  begin
   //...
  end;
```

Note, however, that this will return `True` for all `TList<>` descendants too.

Comment: That's just what I said in last paragraph ;)

Comment: Not just list descendants, but any class with a 'ToArray'. E.g. a TQueue, or a possible TMyListWhichIsNotATList...

Comment: It's not clear from his question what exactly he wants. It could be very possible that checking for `ToArray` would suffice for his needs. And that way he doesn't have to use `Spring`. You can nitpick as much as you want, but my solution is valid too, it just depends what exactly he needs it for.